# How to add a row to spark dataframe according to date if user does not have data on that day? pyspark

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume I have a spark data frame that looks like this.
[image]

Now I want to add rows according to date. for example, if I get the date 09/01/2022 I would like to get this new spark data frame with new rows of ids that didn't have data on that date like this.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your question, try to avoid images and prefer posting your dataframes as text (obtained with `df.show()`) in code blocks. Also, specify what you have already tried to solve your problem. You probably want to have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ... and [mcve] as well

Comment: Was your problem solved by the provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact logic so you may need to refine the solution a little bit but to achieve something that looks like what you want, here is what you could do:

1. group by id and collect the dates as list (+ the metadata)
2. for ids that contain the given date, do nothing
3. for ids that do not, concat a row that looks like what you want
4. explode back the dataframe

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "John", "USA", "Boston", "2022-09-01"),
    (2, "Nick", "USA", "Boston", "2021-03-02"),
    (3, "Andy", "USA", "LA", "2022-09-01"),
    (4, "Lenny", "USA", "Boston", "2021-04-02")
], ['id', 'name', 'country', 'city', 'date'])

some_date = "2022-09-01"

df.groupBy("id", "city")\
  .agg(collect_list("date").alias("dates"),
       collect_list(struct("name", "country", "date")).alias("info"))\
  .withColumn("info", F.when(F.array_contains("dates", some_date), F.col("info"))
        .otherwise(F.concat(F.array(F.struct(F.lit(None).alias("name"),
                                             F.lit(None).alias("country"),
                                             F.lit(some_date).alias("date")
        )), F.col("info"))))\
  .withColumn("info", F.explode("info"))\
  .select("id", "city", "info.*")\
  .show()
```

```
+---+------+-----+-------+----------+
| id|  city| name|country|      date|
+---+------+-----+-------+----------+
|  1|Boston| John|    USA|2022-09-01|
|  2|Boston| null|   null|2022-09-01|
|  2|Boston| Nick|    USA|2021-03-02|
|  3|    LA| Andy|    USA|2022-09-01|
|  4|Boston| null|   null|2022-09-01|
|  4|Boston|Lenny|    USA|2021-04-02|
+---+------+-----+-------+----------+
```